# Making a control to be visible only for a particular amount of time in c#

Tags: c#, controls

I am developing an application where i need the following requirement:

Suppose i have a button and a label (initially visibility set to false) in my form, and user clicks on the button, then the label should be displayed with some text that i assign to the label in the button click. But this label should be displayed only for some time, say some 3 secs and then it should automatically go invisible. For this if i gave:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     label1.Visible=true;
     label1.Text= "Magic";
     Thread.Sleep(3000);
     label1.Visible=false;
    }
```

This code does not help the purpose. What is the approach to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing the last two lines of your method with this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Interval = 3000;
timer.Tick += (source, e) => {label1.Visible = false; timer.Stop();};
timer.Start();
```

Using Thread.Sleep() is never a good idea in WinForms; use timers instead.

Comment: @Daniel: that worked. Simple and Nice. thanks. Can you explain me the third line in the code?

Comment: The third line of code uses a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) to avoid writing a full method (meaning a method with a signature, separate from any other method). It's ideally used in places where you would only need to use the method once - if you need to use it more than once than you should implement a separate method and use an EventHandler to call it.

Comment: @Daniel You should specify which Timer you're using. I can understand it's the System.Windows.Forms.Timer one because of the Tick event, but be aware there are multiple timers available in the framework (System.Threading.Timer, System.Timers.Timer...)

Answer (score 2):

`Create` a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) with 3s as `Interval`, start it, and set `Visible` to `false` in your timer Tick event. Also don't forget to stop the timer.

**Never** call `Thread.Sleep` in your UI thread: the application will be blocked as the UI thread won't accept messages (user click...) while sleeping.

Comment: you don't need to explicitly stop the timer, just make sure it's `AutoReset` property is set to `false`

Comment: @paul There is no such property for the System.Windows.Forms.Timer class (it only exists for the System.Timers.Timer).

Answer (score 2):

```
// create a global _timer object
static Timer _timer; // From System.Timers

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    label1.Text = "Magic";
    // Thread.Sleep(3000); // don't do Thread.Sleep()!
    label1.Visible = false;

    Start();
}


static void Start()
{
    label1.Visible = true;


    _timer = new Timer(3000); // Set up the timer for 3 seconds

    _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
    _timer.Enabled = true; // Enable it

}
static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Visible = false;
    _timer.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Timer, perhaps Windows.Forms.Timer. You may have to play with enabling and disabling it when needed and not needed. Your current way does not help, coz your making the main UI thread to sleep. No use.